# sklearn PCA not producing unique results

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

I'm trying to reproduce something I wrote with another computer. Now with mac I get this weird behaviour. I have no idea what's wrong. Works normally with linux.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
df = df_selected1.values.copy() 
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
for i in range(5):
    pca.fit_transform(df)
    print(pca.explained_variance_)

#output
[ 5.03922837  0.06647913]
[ 15.07182343   1.55837475]
[ 18.83493071   5.11528737]
[ 8.56237035  1.2922362 ]
[ 121.51350407    0.78051842]
```

edit: so it works normally if I have less than rows 60. If I add more I get error

```
LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

example data:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([np.ndarray(90),np.ndarray(90),np.ndarray(90),np.ndarray(90)]).transpose()
```

Comment: Use `random_state` param in `PCA(...)` to make this reproducible.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem

Comment: What doesnt solve the problem? Are you saying that setting random_state to an integer value still results in different results in for loop? Please make a reproducible problem.

Comment: the data that you added do not correspond to the one that you used.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are doing something wrong.

Until you post the 1) full code, 2) data, 3) full error and 4) the versions of the modules, I am going to provide an example using random data.

**Example using 5000 rows and 4 columns.**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5000,4))
df1 = df.copy()
pca = PCA(n_components=2, random_state= 2)
for i in range(10):
     pca.fit_transform(df1)
     print(pca.explained_variance_)

[0.08596479 0.08470371]
[0.08596479 0.08470371]
[0.08596479 0.08470371]
[0.08596479 0.08470371]
[0.08596479 0.08470371]
[0.08596479 0.08470371]
[0.08596479 0.08470371]
[0.08596479 0.08470371]
[0.08596479 0.08470371]
[0.08596479 0.08470371]
```